# Levenshtein distance and triangle inequality

Tags: string, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I am confused about Levenshtein distance and triangle inequality. Wikipedia and other articles say that Levenshtein distance follows triangle inequality.

Triangle inequality states `x+y>z`, but for Levenshtein distance, it appears to me that `x+y` can be equal to `z`. For example, `kitten-> sitting=3`, `kitten->sittin=2` and `sittin->sitting=1`. What am I missing here?

EDIT

The triangle inequality is not in eucledian space, but metric space. In a metric space, the triangle inequality is `d(x,z)<= d(x,y)+d(y,z)`

Comment: Isn't this more a math question? Sure it's an algorithm, but it isn't regarding its implementation. I'm sure there would be some computer scientists just waiting over on math overflow to answer this

Comment: It probably refers to the relaxed triangle inequality x+y<=z (if equal the triangle is degenerate). Click the link to the Triangle Inequality article on Wikipedia for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triangle inequality states `x+y>=z`.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo In the definition of `metric` resp. `distance` the form with `>=` is used: [see Definition on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Definition). In the euclidian space for three points on a line the euclidian distance is exactly `x+y=z`. This is what we do at home when our measuring tape is too short.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention that for a lot of task is used the normalized Levenshtein distance or vice versa similarity. Like distance 2 between words with length 4 and 10 means more 50% and 80% similarity. The normalized Levenshtein distance doesn't satisfy triangle inequality in lot of cases. Therefore is not a metric from mathematical point of view.

However is possible to achieve triangle inequality with the correct normalization of the Levenshtein distance.

Let be Generic Levenshtein Distance (GLD) is normalized Levenshtein distance. The GLD is a metric valued in [0, 1]. Given two strings X and Y with over a finite alphabet with the length |X| and |Y|. The equation for normalization is following:

**GLD(X,Y) = 2*d(X,Y) / (|X|,|Y| + d(X,Y))**

where d(X,Y) is Levenshtein Distance.

This normalization satisfies triangle ineqaulity as results from the article [1].

I used also in my created  Nuget Package - BlueSimilarity[2] common normalization which violates triangle inequality (1 - d(X,Y)/max(|X|,|Y|)).

***Your Example***

X = "kitten", Y = "sitting", Z = "sittin"

GLD(X,Z) <=  GLD(X,Y)+ GLD(Y,Z)

2* d(X,Y) / (|X|,|Y| + d(X,Y)) + 2* d(Y,Z) / (|Y|+|Z| + d(Y,Z)) >= 2*d(X,Z) / (|X|,|Z| + d(X,Z))

2*3 /(6+7+3) + 1 - 2*1/(6+7+1) >= 2*2/(6+6+2)

0.375 + 0.143 >= 0.286

References:

[1] Li Yujian, Liu Bo; A Normalized Levenshtein distance metric; IEEE
Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, 2007

[2] Rozinek, Ondrej; BlueSimilarity;
https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlueSimilarity/

Comment: I may be missing something but this still isn't a metric because it doesn't satisfy d(X, X) = 0 since it would evaluate to 1 - d(X,X)/len(X) = 1 - 0/len(X) = 1.

Comment: The mentioned GLD is a similarity function and it is inverse function of the distance (also could be called dissimalirity). The distance is the term d(X,Y) / MAX(|X|,|Y|) and the similarity 1 - d(X,Y) / MAX(|X|,|Y|). So your resulting 1 is 100% similar object with the distance 0 [the term d(X,X)/len(X)]. We could change rather notation to "GLS". The normalized similarity is more practical for search and pattern matching than the measurement of the absolute distance.

Comment: @OndrejRozinek Should "|X|,|Y|" be "|X|+|Y|" in the formula cited from [1]?